# Using multiple custom validation constraints on the one element?

Tags: javascript, validation, webshim

```
<form>
    <input type="date" id="date1" />
    <input type="time" id="time1" />

    <input type="date" id="date2" />
    <input type="time" id="time2" />
</form>
```

I have two date elements and two time elements on my form. I want to be able to have `date1` required if `time1` is not empty, and the same for `date2` and `time2`.  I also want to have `date2 >= date1` if `date1` is not empty, and similarly `date1 <= date2` if `date2` is not empty.

Using the `data-dependent-validation` jsfiddle sample at http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/demos/forms.html#Custom-validity I can see how to do both of those validation rules, but I can't see how to apply both at the same time. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This currently not possible. But it should be easy to do with DOM scripting conditionally setting required property and changing the min/max properties. In case you need any help let me know. I will create a small fiddle for you.

For the sake of completeness here is a simple fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/trixta/sGNwC/

```
$('.require-if').each(function () {
    var $date = $('input[type="date"]', this);
    var $time = $('input[type="time"]', this);
    $date
        .on('change.requireif', function () {
            if($date.val()){
                $time.prop('required', true);
                if(!$time.prop('value')){
                    $time.prop('value', '00:00');
                }
            } else {
                $time.prop('required', false);
            }
        })
        .trigger('change.requireif')
    ;
});
```

For the min/max I still used dependent-validation and for the required part I wrote the small script above.